# A twice differentiable function $f$ satisfies $f′′(x)+f(x)=−xg(x)f′(x)$, $\forall x\ge 0$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Consider $f\in C^2$ so that $$f''(x)+f(x)=-x\,g(x)f'(x), \ \forall x\ge0 $$ where $g(x)\ge 0$. Then ($\forall x\ge 0$)
>
> - (A) $f(x)^2+f'(x)^2$ is non-increasing,
> - (B) $f(x)^2<3f(0)^2+(2f'(0))^2$,
> - (C) $|f(x)|\le\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a fixed real constant.
> - (D) $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$ exists.

[original task description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2hrr.jpg)

**Answer Given:** (A),(B),(C),(D)

**What I have tried** : I differentiated option (A) and then with the help of the given equation in the question I was able to show that  it is less than zero . Hence I was able to infer that option (A) is correct .

Now coming to option (B). 
I assumed the function in option (A) to be $h(x)$.

$$ h(x) = f(x)^2 + f'(x)^2 $$

Since $h'(x)<0$ ,therefore $h(x)$ is a decreasing function

hence for all $x\ge 0$

$h(x)< h(0)$

which implies $(f(x))^2 + (f'(x))^2<(f(0))^2 + (f'(0))^2$

From the above expression we can get the second option .

**Is my method correct ?. If not , please show the right method .**

**I am unable to get the the 3rd and 4th option .**

Comment: Non-increasing doesn't mean decreasing, so you should actually have $h'(x) \le 0$. This should still work for your solution in (B)

Comment: (B) is not true for the zero solution $f\equiv0$. It may be a nitpick, but it is not excluded in the task. --- If $g$ falls fast enough to zero, perhaps with $g(x)=\exp(-x^2)$, is it possible that the amplitude does not fall to zero for $x\to\infty$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$h(x) = f(x)^2 + f'(x)^2$ is non-increasing (but not necessarily *decreasing*) on $[0, \infty) $ because 
$$
 h'(x) = 2f(x) f'(x)  + 2f'(x) f''(x) = -2 x g(x)f'(x)^2 \le 0 \, ,
$$
so  (A) is true. Then
$$
 f(x)^2 \le h(x) \le h(0) = f(0)^2 + f'(0)^2 \le 3f(0)^2+(2f'(0))^2 \, ,
$$
which is (B) with $\le$ instead of $<$. As already stated in the
comments, the example $f(x) = 0$ shows that equality can hold in (B).

(C) and (D) are true because
$$
 |f(x)| \le \sqrt{h(0)} =: \alpha
$$
and
$$
\left|\, f(x) \sin \left(\frac 1x\right) \right| \le \frac{\alpha}{x} \to 0 \text{ for } x \to \infty \, .
$$

Comment: This maybe a bit crass but I still want to ask . 
It is clear that f(x)^2 <=h(0) from the expression.
How did you get the modulus ? .
Thank you for the answering the question .

Comment: @Alphanerd: $f(x)$ is a real number, therefore $|f(x)|^2 = f(x)^2 \le h(0)^2$.

Comment: (Of course it should be $|f(x)|^2 = f(x)^2 \le h(0)$.)